# Example of Parseval's Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, power-series

In the textbook "Mathematics for Physics" of Stone and Goldbart the following example for an illustration of Parseval's Theorem is given:
[image]

[image]

Until 2.42 I understand everything but I don't understand the statement:

" Finally, as $\sin^2(\pi(\zeta-n))=\sin^2(\pi \zeta)$ "

Can you explain me why this equality holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin{\pi n} = 0$ when $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Thus, because $\cos{\pi n} = (-1)^n$, we have

$$\sin{\pi (\zeta - n)} = \sin{\pi \zeta} \cos{\pi n} - \sin{\pi n} \cos{\pi \zeta} = (-1)^n \sin{\pi \zeta} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let's work it out from first principles. Recall that
$$\sin(a+b)=\cos(b)\sin(a)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
Now, we consider $\sin(\pi(\zeta-n))=\sin(\pi\zeta-\pi n)$, i.e. $a=\pi\zeta$ and $b=-\pi n$:
\begin{align}\sin(\pi\zeta-\pi n)&=\cos(-\pi n)\sin(\pi\zeta)+\cos(\pi\zeta)\sin(-\pi n)\\
&=\cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi\zeta)-\cos(\pi\zeta)\sin(\pi n)\end{align}
where we have used that:
\begin{align}\cos(-\theta)&=\cos(\theta)\\\sin(-\theta)&=-\sin(\theta)\end{align}
And by periodicity (since $n$ is an integer):
\begin{align}\cos(\pi n)&=\pm 1\\\sin(\pi n)&=0\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{align}\sin(\pi\zeta-\pi n)&=\pm\sin(\pi\zeta)\\
\sin^2(\pi\zeta-\pi n)&=\left[\pm\sin(\pi\zeta)\right]^2\\
&=\sin^2(\pi\zeta)\end{align}